# Is it possible to use the vis-timeline inside a web component?

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element, vis.js

Is it possible to use the [vis-timeline](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/issues/new) inside a web component? I am trying to set up a angular web component with a timeline inside of it, and the web component is being renderized correctly apart from the timeline, but the timeline is not being rendered at all. Is this even possible to achieve? If i change the encapsulation of the `App.component.ts` from `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` it works fine, since it is no longer inside a shadowroot.

The component:

```js
export class TimelineComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('visualization', { static: true }) timelineContainer: ElementRef;

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.options = this.getOptions();
    this.groups = this.getTimelineGroups();
    this.items = this.getItems();

    this.timeline = new Timeline(
      this.timelineContainer.nativeElement,
      this.items,
      this.groups,
      this.options
    );
  }
}
```

the html:

```html
<div class='timeline-container' #visualization>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time digging into the problem, the short answer is yes, it can be used inside a web component. The only problem is that the library appends the styles to the document, and then all the styles are lost and the heights are also not correct. So, the temporary solution was to @import the minified css inside the web component. The vis-timeline, still appends the styles to the document, it gets duplicated after the @import and can be a problem if some class has the same name as the vis-timeline html classes. So, its a temporary solution.